# OSMDROID: load offline tiles from database

Tags: java, android, osmdroid, mbtiles

I have .mbtiles database with tiles:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfWlg.png)

How can i load tiles into Map View? The examples from the Internet do not work. My code shows a gray default screen:

```
public void getTilesFromArchive(Context context, MapView mMapView, String currentPath) {
    File f = new File(currentPath);

    OfflineTileProvider tileProvider = new OfflineTileProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(context),
            new File[]{f});
    mMapView.setTileProvider(tileProvider);
    String source = "";
    IArchiveFile[] files = new IArchiveFile[1];
    files = tileProvider.getArchives();

    if (files != null) {
        Set<String> tileSources = files[0].getTileSources();
        if (!tileSources.isEmpty()) {
            source = tileSources.iterator().next();
            mMapView.setTileSource(FileBasedTileSource.getSource(source));
        }
    }
}
```

files != null, but files[0].getTileSources() is always null.
What I must do?.. Please, help